# SQL Query : Filter out results that are included in other results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite , I have a table with names:

```
[Data]
"John"
"John"
"John"
"John.wane"
```

When I query :

```
SELECT * from [TABLE] Group By Data
```

I get:

```
John
John.wane
```

How can I filers columns that are included in other columns ?
Is this example , "John" is included in "John,.Wane" 
so "John.Wane" should not be present at the query result.

Comment: Just a side note: Don't use `GROUP BY` when you don't aggregate anything (i.e. use `MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT`, etc.). Your query should be `SELECT DISTINCT data from [TABLE]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for names that are not contained in other names. This is a bit difficult. Okay, 'John' is in 'John.wane', but is it also in 'Bobby.John.wane' or even in 'John.waned'?

Here is a query getting only names for which don't exist other name entries containing the name. Adjust the `InStr` expression according to your wishes.

```
select data 
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.data <> mytable.data
  and instr(other.data, mytable.data) > 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t2.Data IS NOT NULL THEN t2.Data ELSE t1.Data END 
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t2 
ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.Data <> t2.Data AND t1.Data LIKE  '%' || t2.Data || '%' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t2.Data IS NOT NULL THEN t2.Data ELSE t1.Data END
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me (#tmp is a temporary table for the example) :

```
select 'John' as Data
into #tmp
union
select 'John' as Data
union
select 'John' as Data
union
select 'John' as Data
union
select 'John.Wane' as Data

select t1.Data 
from #tmp t1
where t1.Data not in 
(
    select t3.Data
    from #tmp t2
    cross join #tmp t3
    where t2.Data != t3.Data 
    and t3.Data not like REPLACE(t3.Data, t2.Data, '') + '%'
)
group by t1.Data

drop table #tmp
```